# Writing Video Files in Java

Tags: java, file, video

I'm trying to find a way to save a video file. Initially I'd put the video files as blob data into a database, and now, I'm trying to get the blob data back, convert it into bytes, and then write it to a new file. I've been successful in doing this, but the problem is, I can't make the resulting files to run. I tried storing, retrieving, and writing .flv and .mp4 files, but neither work :/ Can anyone help me? Much appreciated! :)

Here is my code: :)

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root","password");  
    Statement st1 = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT video_file from video where video_id = " + video_id);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    Blob blob = null;
    byte[] blyte = null;
    if(rs.next()) {
        blob = rs.getBlob("video_file");
        InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Downloads\\file2.mp4");
        int b = 0;
        while(b != -1){
            fos.write(b);
            b = bis.read();
        }
    }
//exceptions beyond this point
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
} catch (SQLException e) {
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us your code, otherwise we can't help. You can modify your question by clicking on the "edit" link below the tags. Also you might want to read [ask], and maybe [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: thank you for the reply. Umm, I'd been researching on saving it to file and thought it'd be quite straightforward, and again, I have already saved the files, but I just can't make them run on my media players. Just thought I had to do something else to make the files work? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: nevermind the blyte variable, I was using it before, but I didn't anymore, and haven't deleted it yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a '\0' byte written to fos in first iteration of the while-loop which does not come from bis.read().

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice that at all! Thank you so much! :)